# .net core 2.0 Cant download file saved in folder.

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, download, asp.net-core-2.0

I save info from datagrid to xslx file located at the folder, after I want to download this file.
I have code, that is working correct, but in my project when I try to download file it return nothing. Maybe it because of protection or user role is admin.
I have tried with different folders, and I'm sure that folder is not a problem.
What else it can be?

```
 public FileResult downloadFile(string filePath)
            {
                IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(filePath);
                IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(fileName);
                var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
                var mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                return File(readStream, mimeType, fileName);
            }
```

Comment: What filePath are you sending to that function, please write an example

Comment: fileName = "SN-export.xlsx";                   
                    string filePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;                    
                    string fileName2 = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
                    FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName2);
                    if (excelFile.Exists)
                    {
                        excelFile.Delete();
                        excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName2);
                    }
                    excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
                    return downloadFile(filePath);

Answer (score 0):

I have try your code and everthing seems ok

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var fileName = "SN-export.xlsx";
    string filePath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    string fileName2 = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(fileName2);
    if (excelFile.Exists) {
        excelFile.Delete();
        excelFile =  new FileInfo(fileName2);
    }
    // excel.SaveAs(excelFile); Have to comment this because i don't know what excel nuget you are using
    // For testing purpose i have used the following two lines
    var file = System.IO.File.Create(excelFile.ToString());
    file.Close();
    return DownloadFile(filePath, fileName);
}

public FileResult DownloadFile(string filePath,string fileName)
{ 
    IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(filePath);
    IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo(fileName);
    var readStream = fileInfo.CreateReadStream();
    var mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    return File(readStream, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Comment: I tested at the simple project my code as well, and it's working, I know this. But it isn't working in my project. I thought that it may be because of admin role in my project or authorization. Have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: If you think that's a role problem, put [AllowAnonymous] before each method and try it.